# How to query InfluxDB using WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, webclient, influxdb

I'm trying to write a simple query command. Documentaion for http for influxDB is [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/guides/querying_data/).

This is what I have so far:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("root", "root");
var reponse = client.UploadString("http://localhost:8080/query", "db=dbName\"q = SELECT \"something\" FROM \"tableName\" WHERE \"tag\"='valueTag'");
```

I'm getting "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.". Is it because the urlencode is not the same as putting as the string for the data part of client.UploadString?

Answer (score 1):

WebClient.UploadString sends data as part of a POST request, which isn't what you want for this operation. Instead, your query should be URL-encoded and sent as HTTP GET parameters in the request URL. This can be achieved using `Uri.EscapeUriString` and `WebClient.DownloadString`:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var queryString = Uri.EscapeUriString("db=dbName&q=SELECT \"something\" FROM \"tableName\" WHERE \"tag\"='valueTag'");
var queryUrl = "http://localhost:8086/query?" + queryString;
var response = client.DownloadString(queryUrl);
```

Also note that HTTP GET parameters are separated by an ampersand and there must not be whitespace between the key/value names and the `=` or `&`. For example `?k1=v1&k2=v2` is well-formed whereas `?k1=v1&k1 = v1` is not.

Comment: that code does not seem to work for me. I get an error of bad request 400. I made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797900/400-bad-request-error-when-trying-to-insert-into-influxdb-enterprise-server-but . I think it has something to do with credentials