# 400 Bad Request Error when trying to insert into InfluxDB enterprise server but working when inserting into local server

Tags: c#, .net, influxdb

The same C# code that works for inserting into local server works but not for actual server.

I think it has to do with credentials?

```
using (System.Net.WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    //test
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pw");
    client.UploadString(new Uri($"{Settings.influxDBServer}/write?db={Settings.influxDatabaseName}"), sb.ToString());
}
```

In local server username/pw isn't required. For enterprise it is. So I added the `client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pw");` line. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044313/webclient-httpwebrequest-with-basic-authentication-returns-404-not-found-for-v) and tried the answer by jitbit but I still get error 400.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Will {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}

Comment: @JJSSOQ something about your request is badly formed. [InfluxDB docs say](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/query_language/authentication_and_authorization/#authentication-and-authorization-http-errors) that a 401 or 403 will be returned if there is a problem with credentials. Can you output the full Uri you are passing and also the contents of `sb.ToString()`?

Comment: @Will It will insert into local server with no problem but not the enterprise one that requires credentials.

sb.Tostring()-->
{infoLog,ServerName=s001,ServerPort=39620,CacheType=abc-p.1,FarmType=Dev ConnectedClients=9,BlockedClients=0,UsedMemory=12900664,UsedMemoryPeak=31990728,InstantaneousOpsPerSec=8,RejectedConnections=0,KeyspaceHits=318,KeyspaceMisses=105,ConnectedSlaves=0 15131232000000000}

ResponseUri = {http://example0005:8086/write?db=CachePreprocessor}